# How does heteroskedasticity affect individual prediction intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, prediction, heteroscedasticity

In a simple linear regression model:

Would heteroskedastic residuals that show increasing variance of the residuals as X increases- cause the individual prediction intervals to be not wide enough at higher levels of X and too wide at lower levels of X?